# Reusing a Control in another Windows Forms Project

Tags: winforms, controls, code-reuse

I've got lots of web experience but am a total novice when it comes to [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) so this might be easy to answer:

I have Project1 which I've added a reusable control to which allows filtering and searching of data and presenting results.

I now want to use the same control in another Project.

When I open Project1 and select my form the reusable control appears on the toolbar so I can drag it onto any form in the project, but how do I get this to happen in my new Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a reference to the (binary) control:

> menu Project/Add Reference/tab Browse

Then it should turn up in the Toolbox (menu View/Toolbox).

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Peter.

The Control is called Extract but I dont see a binary for it after I build the solution. Am I missing a setting?

Comment: You need to add the assembly in which the control resides.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what I've done. I should point out these two Projects are in seperate Solutions if that makes a difference? I added a reference in Project2 to the compiled .exe of project1 but I can't add the Control onto a form in Project2.

Comment: Ah ok, got it working, I needed to add references of the controls dependencies in too.  Dont think this is right but it gets me over this hurdle for now and I'll sort it later.  Thanks guys